# I have a gridview control populated from a database! I want to add a button with text property "reserve" at the end of each row of the gridview.

Tags: asp.net, sql

Depending on whichh button is pressed I have to take the excursion_date_id which I will need in the next form!

SO what is best to use - buttonfield property maybe!

here is my code

First it's the Dates.class

```
public class Dates
   {
        private int excursionID;
        private DateTime startdates;
        private double prices;
    public  int ExcursionID
    {
        get { return excursionID; }
        set { excursionID = value; }

    }
    public DateTime StartDates
    {
        get { return startdates; }
        set { startdates = value; }

   }

    public  double Prices
    {
        get { return prices; }
        set { prices = value; }
    }


    public Dates()
    { }


   }
```

}

Then I populate the gridview with the dates from my database
I want to have a button with text property "reserve" at the end of each row of the gridview!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string excursionnId = Request.QueryString["ExcursionId"];


        Dates date = new Dates();
        List<Dates> listDate = new List<Dates>();
        listDate = GetDates();
        gvDates.DataSource = listDate;
        gvDates.DataBind();

    }

    public List<Dates> GetDates()
    {
        List<Dates> datesList = new List<Dates>();

        string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EXCURSIONSDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=true";
        string excursionnID = Request.QueryString["ExcursionID"];
        string query =
    "SELECT Excursion_date_ID, Excursion_ID, Start_date, Price FROM EXCURSION_DATES WHERE EXCURSION_ID='" + excursionnID + "'";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int s=0;
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                Dates dates = new Dates();

                dates.ExcursionID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Excursion_ID"]);
                dates.StartDates = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["Start_date"]);
                dates.Prices = Convert.ToDouble(rd["Price"]);
                datesList.Add(dates);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {

        }
        return datesList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDates" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                    OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Button ID="btn" CausesValidation="false"    CommandName="YourCommandName" 
                         CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Excursion_ID") %>' runat="server" Text="Text" />

                              </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView> 
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        string number = (string)e.CommandArgument;
        if (number==null) return;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
          case "YourCommandName":
                Load(number);
                break;

        // some others command
         }
    }
```

OR without rowcommand

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDates" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Button ID="btn" CausesValidation="false"     OnClick="btnClick" 
                     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Excursion_ID") %>' runat="server"  Text="Text" />

                          </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView> 
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn=(Button)sender;
    if(btn==null) return;
    string number = (string)btn.CommandArgument;
    if (number==null) return;

    Load(number);


}
```

Comment: If you need you can join Excursion_ID and Excursion_date_ID with some separator (like  ';' for example) and after split it. CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Excursion_ID")+";" Eval("Excursion_date_ID")%>'

Comment: exuse me for the questrion but how to mark the answer as accepted! I don't see howto mark it

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: hey i want to ask you - now it gives "system doiesn't contain definition for command argument" when i write         string number = (string)e.CommandArgument;
do you know the reason for this beghavior?

Comment: Do You use asp:GridView component?

Comment: yes I use asp:gridview component of course! what have you modified in answer?

Comment: if(number== null) return and added switch :)  But You can convert CommandArgument to int if Your Id was  int type. About "system doiesn't contain definition for command argument"  It very often occures as syntactic   error  reason

Comment: Did you define OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand" property for your gridview?

Comment: yes of course I have defined grd_RowCommand but still it cannot recognize e.CommandArgument  The exception is 'SYSTEM..GRIDVIEW DOESN'T CONTAIN DEFINITION 'COMMANDARGUMENT'

Answer (score 0):

In your .aspx page, specify the id of the GridView button to the ExcursionID. You can use buttonfield or place a button in a template column for that.

Comment: would you send me an example! how to specify the id of the button to teh excursion_date_id!!